# How to properly implement method cascading - chaining in Python?

Tags: python, chaining

I have a python code roughly like this:

```python
class SomeClass():

    def get_date(self):
        date = # read the data from the database in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format
        return date
```

now, I will use the returned value in an API query, which accepts the input as a unix timestamp. Actually I can give the returned date to another function to have it converted to a timestamp, but I thought it would be a good opportunity to learn about function cascading / chaining, which I've always wondered about in Python.

Now, what I basically want to achieve is something like this:

- If I just execute `SomeClass.get_date()`, I want to have the date in the same format that has been returned from the database, which is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
- If I execute `SomeClass.get_date().as_timestamp()`, I should get it as timestamp.
- If not possible, I would settle for having it like `SomeClass.get_date().as_datetime()` and `SomeClass.get_date().as_timestamp()`
- I might use the second function (`.as_timestamp()`) for more than one primary function (there are multiple datetime columns that I may need to be converted into timestamp).

I've looked into some examples of function cascading. They are mostly saying that key to this is returning the `self`, but I could not find any info about how to implement it in the way I need to.

I basically need the return value to be fed into the second function (I guess), but not sure if it is possible, and don't know how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: `get_date` is going to have to return *some object* that has the rest of the methods you want to use. You could have the `__str__` of the Date object use the default representation, then have each of the other methods return other specific formatting.

Comment: The type of cascade you are referring to typically involves methods that *mutate* the object, and involve method calls that aren't really related to one another. In Python, such methods usually return `None` to emphasize that the object is being mutated (if the method doesn't return anything, why else you be calling it?). What you want to do is simply invoke a method on the return value of another method without using a temporary variable to store an intermediate value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for looks more like this:

```
import time
import calendar

class DateClass():

  def get_date(self):
    self = # read the data from the database in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format
    return self

  def as_timestamp(self):
    mysql_time = time.strptime(self, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    self = calendar.timegm(mysql_time)
    return self

d = DateClass()
print(d.get_date())
print(d.get_date().as_timestamp())
print(d)
d.get_date()
print(d)
```

The first output would be the MySQL datetime, and the second would be the Unix timestamp, the third would also be the unix timestamp and the fourth would be the datetime.  `get_date()` and `as_timestamp()` mutate the instance `d` when called on it.

In this configuration, `as_timestamp()` requires `get_date()`, which seems to be in line with your question, but you could change that by assigning `self` from the database in `as_timestamp()` like this:

```
def as_timestamp(self):
  self = # read the data from the database in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format
  mysql_time = time.strptime(self, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  self = calendar.timegm(mysql_time)
  return self
```

which will make it possible to call `as_timestamp()` independent of `get_date()`.  You can also then add `d.as_timestamp()` to mutate any iteration of `d` so that `d` is a timestamp.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! I've always thought that function chaining facilities some method that involves taking previous function's output and operating on that. It's relieving to see that it is actually a lot simpler than that :)

Comment: ...also known as [Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)